# c# use Calendar.SelectedDate in a repeater control, but month is giving me "00"

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to make a webform using asp.net.
When a linked button is clicked (within a repeater), a calendar is supposed to popup. The date selected on the calendar is supposed to fill out the text box "start date".

This is one item inside Repeater1:

```
<td>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStart" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"StartDate") %>' />
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCalendar" runat="server" 
      CssClass="btn btn-xs"OnClick="ShowCalendar">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </asp:LinkButton>
</td>
```

After all other items, here is the Calendar:

```
 <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Visibile="false"  SelectionMode="Day" onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged">
                  </asp:Calendar>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (Repeater1.Items.Count == 1)
    {
        TextBox txtStart = (TextBox)Repeater1.Items[0].FindControl("txtStart");
        DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;

        txtStart.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyymmdd");
    }
```

This code behind is just adding text to the fist item of the repeater

**My problem is:**

**The SelectedDate of Calendar is giving me the correct year and date, but is giving me value "00" for the month**

[This is the link to a screenshot of the part of my webform which is problematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SJgH.png)

Thank you!

Comment: The dateformat string is imperfect, mm is minutes, MM is months, you want: Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

Comment: @Davesoft Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the line

```
 txtStart.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyymmdd");
```

with

```
 txtStart.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```